# Netbeans/JavaFX Application Subclass Missing

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, ria, netbeans-7.3

When I create a new JavaFX application in Netbeans 7.3 (and choose "Create Application Class") no such class is created. Not even the package for it -- just an empty default package.

I assume that I could just create it manually by extending the 'Application' class but maybe this behaviour is symptomatic of some setup anomaly.

Any idea why this happens? Btw, I had the same issue with Netbeans 7.1.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate your issue.

This works for me.  In NetBeans 7.3:

1. Create a new JavaFX Project:

   `File | New Project | JavaFX | JavaFX Application` (click `Next`)
2. Enter the project name, for example `TestProject` (click `Finish):

   The screen has a checked checkbox `Create application class`.
   The default application class name will be `testproject.TestProject`
   You can edit the default application class name to change it and the package it is located in if you like.
3. A skeleton Application class is created:

   The `TestProject` class extends `Application` and resides in the `testproject` package.

---

To create more applications in the same project:

1. Right click on the Project, choose:

   New | Other | JavaFX | JavaFX Main Class (click `Next`).
2. Enter a class name, for example `NewFXMain`
3. From the package drop down choose a project package, for example `testproject` (click `Finish`).
4. Another skeleton Application class is created:

   The `NewFXMain` class extends `Application` and resides in the `testproject` package.

[image: newjavafxclass]

Comment: Thanks, but this is the way I've done it. However, the issue is now resolved. Apparently, something must have messed up the environment when I installed the 7.3 and imported my previous 7.1 projects because many useful libraries were also missing. I reinstalled the 7.3 without bothering with importing anything from the previous version, and now everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. Apparently, something must have messed up the environment when I installed the 7.3 and imported my previous 7.1 projects because many useful libraries were also missing. I reinstalled the 7.3 without bothering with importing anything from the previous version, and now everything works like a charm.